# What is the purpose of "undoing" steps after a recursive call (JAVA)?

Tags: java, recursion, permutation

This is a snippet to create all possible permutations of an integer array. I would specifically like to know the purpose of the line when the last element is removed from the tempList. I have tried to add print statements everywhere, but I am still not conceptually understanding the recursive backtracking that takes place.

```
public List<List<Integer>> permute(int[] nums) {
   List<List<Integer>> list = new ArrayList<>();
   // Arrays.sort(nums); // not necessary
   backtrack(list, new ArrayList<>(), nums);
   return list;
}

private void backtrack(List<List<Integer>> list, List<Integer> tempList, int [] nums){
   if(tempList.size() == nums.length){
      list.add(new ArrayList<>(tempList));
   } else{
      for(int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++){ 
         if(tempList.contains(nums[i])) continue; // element already exists, skip
         tempList.add(nums[i]);
         backtrack(list, tempList, nums);
         tempList.remove(tempList.size() - 1);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Keep you print statements so you can see what happens, then comment out the `remove` call to see how it fails without it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what your `backtrack` function is doing:

1) Check if the length of the current list is same as total numbers which mean all numbers are added in the list. In that case, create a new list with the same sequence and add it in the final list of list and will return back from the current recursive call.

2) Iterate over all the numbers and check if any number does not exist in that list. That is the reason for all the numbers that exist in the list, continue is there, which is skipping the loop. If all the number already exists, it will return from the existing recursive call.

3) Add the nonexisting number in the list and again call backtrack which will again execute No. 1 and No. 2

4) Once we have reached a scenario when all the numbers are added by No. 1 for some permutation, the last line will delete the number added by current recursive call from the `tempList`, so that the same list can be used for other different permutations. Once deleted, it will return back to the previous recursive call.

This is how it is running when I executed for a small example of `{1,2,3}`

```
Inside backtrack iteration 1
1 does not exist in the current list and hence adding
Inside backtrack iteration 2
2 does not exist in the current list and hence adding
Inside backtrack iteration 3
3 does not exist in the current list and hence adding
Inside backtrack iteration 4
Another List finalized [1, 2, 3]
3  is deleted,making list back to [1, 2]
2  is deleted,making list back to [1]
3 does not exist in the current list and hence adding
Inside backtrack iteration 3
2 does not exist in the current list and hence adding
Inside backtrack iteration 4
Another List finalized [1, 3, 2]
2  is deleted,making list back to [1, 3]
3  is deleted,making list back to [1]
1  is deleted,making list back to []
2 does not exist in the current list and hence adding
Inside backtrack iteration 2
1 does not exist in the current list and hence adding
Inside backtrack iteration 3
3 does not exist in the current list and hence adding
Inside backtrack iteration 4
Another List finalized [2, 1, 3]
3  is deleted,making list back to [2, 1]
1  is deleted,making list back to [2]
3 does not exist in the current list and hence adding
Inside backtrack iteration 3
1 does not exist in the current list and hence adding
Inside backtrack iteration 4
Another List finalized [2, 3, 1]
1  is deleted,making list back to [2, 3]
3  is deleted,making list back to [2]
2  is deleted,making list back to []
3 does not exist in the current list and hence adding
Inside backtrack iteration 2
1 does not exist in the current list and hence adding
Inside backtrack iteration 3
2 does not exist in the current list and hence adding
Inside backtrack iteration 4
Another List finalized [3, 1, 2]
2  is deleted,making list back to [3, 1]
1  is deleted,making list back to [3]
2 does not exist in the current list and hence adding
Inside backtrack iteration 3
1 does not exist in the current list and hence adding
Inside backtrack iteration 4
Another List finalized [3, 2, 1]
1  is deleted,making list back to [3, 2]
2  is deleted,making list back to [3]
3  is deleted,making list back to []
```

Comment: very good explanation!